Error: ReplaceRepeated: ...is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, \ and so cannot be used for replacing
I want to solve the following PDE. I use images to demonstrate derivatives since they are clearer. I discovered that I can only have the function's derivative inside the PDE, not its original form. If I replace the 0 with logf[lp,k,t], there will be a lot of errors, as seen in the third figure, but everything will be alright if I continue to use 0.



Here's the code for solving the PDE using NDSolve
Do[
  Clear[logf];
  \[Tau]i = \[Tau]vals[[i]];
  \[Tau]f = \[Tau]vals[[i + 1]];
  
  \[Tau]ini = \[Tau]i;
  IaNow = getIa[Exp[logfNow[lp, \[Kappa]]]];
  IbNow = getIb[Exp[logfNow[lp, \[Kappa]]]];
  lCbNow = getlCb[Exp[logfNow[lp, \[Kappa]]]];
  inicond = logfNow[lp, \[Kappa]];
  
  Print["i = ", i, ". \[Tau]i = ", \[Tau]i, ". \[Tau]f = ", \[Tau]f];
  Print["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(a\)]\) = ", IaNow, ". Ib = ", 
   IbNow,  " .lCb = ", lCbNow];
  
  sol = NDSolve[eqn, 
    logf, {lp, lp0, lpf}, {\[Kappa], 
     0, \[Kappa]f}, {\[Tau], \[Tau]i, \[Tau]f}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> maxcell}}}];
  Print["NDSolve finished"];
  
  \[Tau]ftemp = \[Tau]vals[[i + 1]];
  
  logfNow[lp_, \[Kappa]_] := 
   logf[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]ftemp] //. sol[[1]];
  Print[logfNow[lp, \[Kappa]]];
  
  , {i, 1, Length[\[Tau]vals] - 1}];
```

